# Refreshing a div creates a duplicate in struts2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I'm new to Javascript so please bear with me.

I have code which refreshes the div of the parent window when the child window closes. The problem is when content of the div refreshes it creates a duplicate, and I don't know why. My code is below.

Inside the `head` tag of the parent I'm doing this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ParentWindowFunction()
{
    $(".mydiv").load("Welcome.jsp");
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="mydiv">
    <img src="<s:property  value="#session.img"/>"  id="img"  width="200"  height="150" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Inside child window's `head` tag I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshAndClose() 
{

    window.opener.ParentWindowFunction();

    window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body  onbeforeunload="refreshAndClose();">
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your response also contain an element having a `mydiv` as part of class name?

Comment: What is returned by `Welcome.jsp`? Does it also contain a `<div class="mydiv">` in its body?

Comment: @RobinMaben Yes Robin, only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution for my problem instead of refreshing div i am reloading entire page like this

```
<script>     
    function winopen()
    {
        chatterinfo = window.open('fileupload.jsp',"chatterwin","scrollbars=no,resizable=yes, width=400, height=300, location=no, toolbar=no, status=no");

        chatterinfo.focus();        
    }
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ParentWindowFunction()
    {
        window.location="Login.action?uname=${uname}&&pass=${pass}";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="mydiv">
<img src="<s:property  value="#session.img"/>"  id="img"  width="200"  height="150" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside child window's head tag I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshAndClose() 
    {
        window.opener.ParentWindowFunction();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body >
<input type=button onclick="refreshAndClose();" />
</body>
</html>
```